# Theming composer extension's views

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php, yii2-basic-app

I have extension for Yii 2 which is required by Composer.

Inside extension's root directory I have `Module.php` inherited from `Module`, also it implements `BootstrapInterface`. Method `bootstrap` defines some alias, for example `@xxx`.

Inside main app's config I have following:

```
  'modules' => [
      'xxx' => [
          'class' => 'yii\xxx\Module',
      ],
  ],
```

It connects my module to the application. Also I have my module in `bootstrap` array.

My aim is to redefine some views from this extension in base app (create theme for it). According to the Yii 2 documentation I should have something like this:

```
    'view' => [
        'theme' =>[
            'pathMap' => [
                '???' => '@app/theme'
            ],
        ]
    ]
```

But my problem is that I don't know what to write instead of `???`. I've tried these variants: `@xxx/views`, `@vendor/<contributor>/<extension>/views`, `@app/modules/xxx/views`, etc. Everything fails. I've also tried to redefine some views from base app and there were no problems in it. Are there any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused because of using repository with `path` type in `composer.json`. Replaced relative path with absolute without any aliases and it works. I don't know, why it behaves that way

Answer (score 0):

In some case i have used

```
 'view' => [
    'theme' =>[
        'pathMap' => [
           '@vendorName/moduleName/views'  => '@app/theme'
         ],
      ]
  ]
```

If the vendor don't have an alias try to build  a proper path for the vendor/module/views .. dir

Comment: @vendor/<vendorName>/<moduleName>/views getAlias shows right path, but there is no result

Comment: You have a @app/theme dir with corresponding views?

Comment: Yes, it has files in <controleller>/<action>.php